# change character in string

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm

My issue is that I cannot change each bits of my pointer

my function has the same synopsis of memset

I don't know where I'm wrong thanks for helping

```
void *changEachBits(void *, int , size_t)

[BITS 64]

global changEachBits

section .text

changEachBits:
        push rbp
        mov rbp, rsp
        xor rcx, rcx

cdn_loop:
        cmp rcx, rdx
        jz end
        mov [rdi + rcx], rsi
        inc rcx
        jmp cdn_loop
end:
        mov rax, rcx
        mov rsp, rbp
        pop rbp
        ret
```

Comment: what is the value of RDX in the function entry ? can you also shed more light what your function intention is ?

Comment: My function has the same behaviour as memset(3), then RDX has a size in it. Do I answer to your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mov byte [rdi + rcx], rsi`
You should check that indeed the emitted opcodes treat your array as byte array

Comment: Surely not `PTR` for Nasm. Won't assemble anyway. Maybe `sil`?

Comment: @Frank Kotler Thx for your comment !, I've edited my answer to comply w/ NASM syntax

Comment: I try what you told, but i cannot `mov byte[rdi], sil`. I reach a Segfault during tests

Comment: I ask my question in another way . How can I put one char in a string in aim to change one of its character at the second position